# UITableViewCell not removed from the UITableView when using reloaddata

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm using a tableview to display some categories in a left menu. When you select it, the data in the cells changes to courses ('Cursussen') within that category.

Each cell contains an `UIImageView` and an `UILabel`.

I noticed a while ago that when you select a course in the left menu, the label will change to that of a category. That wasn't a big issue back then, but now that I'm working to disable certain courses if they are not available it suddenly became a big issue. To indicate a course that's not available, I'm setting `label.enabled = false`, which works fine, however I also need to prevent the user from tapping on it and navigating to a course that's not available. To do that, I'm using `tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` where I check whether the `UILabel` is enabled. If it's disabled the App won't navigate to the course.

Back to the issue, tapping on a course that is unavailable (which is displaying the correct image and label) will trigger the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` delegate, but when I dequeue the `Cell` and check whether the `UILabel` in it is disabled it so happens to be enabled instead and furthermore the `label.text` does not equal the value I see in the App.

**State before selecting a row:**
[image: unselected]

**State after selecting a row:**
[image: selected]

**cellForRowAtIndexPath method:**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("LeftCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        let label = cell.contentView.subviews[0] as! UILabel
        let image = cell.contentView.subviews[1] as! UIImageView
        if(selectedCategory.ID > 0 || searchCursusses.count > 0) {
            //Category is selected, load course into cell
            var cursus : Cursus
            if(selectedCategory.ID > 0) {
                cursus = cursusses[indexPath.row] as Cursus
            } else {
                cursus = searchCursusses[indexPath.row] as Cursus
            }
            image.image = self.chooseImage(false, name: cursus.category!.Name)
            label.numberOfLines = 0
            label.text = cursus.name
            label.lineBreakMode = .ByTruncatingTail
            if(defaults.boolForKey("offline-mode")) {
                let realm = try! Realm()
                let videos = realm.objects(DownloadedVideo).filter("video.cursus.ID = %@", cursus.ID)
                if(videos.count > 0) {
                    label.enabled = true
                } else {
                    label.enabled = false
                }
            } else {
                label.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
            }
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
            cell.setSelected(false, animated: false)
        } else {
            let category = categories[indexPath.row] as Category
            image.image = self.chooseImage(false, name: category.Name)
            label.numberOfLines = 0
            label.text = category.Name
            label.lineBreakMode = .ByTruncatingTail
            label.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
        }
        return cell
}
```

**didSelectRowAtIndexPath method:**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier( "LeftCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.selectionStyle = .None
    if(selectedCategory.ID > 0 || searchCursusses.count > 0) {
        let label = cell.contentView.subviews[0] as! UILabel
        if(!label.enabled) {
            return
        }
        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        let resultViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CursusView") as! CursusViewController
        if(selectedCategory.ID > 0) {
            resultViewController.loadCursus(self.cursusses[indexPath.row], completionHandler: {
                self.presentViewController(resultViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
            })
        } else {
            resultViewController.loadCursus(self.searchCursusses[indexPath.row], completionHandler: {
                self.presentViewController(resultViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
            })
        }
    } else {
        let category = categories[indexPath.row] as Category
        cell.setSelected(true, animated: false)
        let label = cell.contentView.subviews[0] as! UILabel
        let image = cell.contentView.subviews[1] as! UIImageView
        if(label.textColor == UIColor.lightGrayColor()) {
            return
        } else {
            image.image = self.chooseImage(true, name: category.Name)
            label.numberOfLines = 0
            label.text = category.Name
            label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            label.lineBreakMode = .ByTruncatingTail
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 45.0/255.0, green: 145.0/255.0, blue: 220.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
            self.selectedCategory = category
            self.topBarTitle.text = category.Name
            let realm = try! Realm()
            let cursusses = realm.objects(Cursus).filter("category.ID = %@", selectedCategory.ID)
            for cursus in cursusses {
                self.cursusses.append(cursus)
            }
            let title = self.leftMenuNav.subviews[0] as! UILabel
            let titleImg = self.leftMenuNav.subviews[1] as! UIImageView
            titleImg.image = UIImage(named: "back-icon")
            title.text = "Cursussen"
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                self.tableView.slideInFromRight(0.5)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                self.collectionView.crossFade(0.3)
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            })
        }
    }
}
```

It seems the old cells are not properly cleaned up after calling `reloaddata`, causing multiple cells to be at the same IndexPath.

I'm at a loss here, please help!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the line

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier( "LeftCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
```

in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` function because it is creating a new cell (or trying to reuse one) and corrupting the table view cell cache.

You should be getting the existing cell instead using the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function.

Comment: Thanks! I did not think of calling `cellForRowAtIndexPath` inside `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. Thanks to your answer I could keep the functionality to change the image to a white version when selected.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with your approach: `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is supposed to look at the data in the *model*, not in the *view*. Your code is trying, incorrectly, to access the `cell` and examine its labels etc. Instead, your method should be accessing the same underlying data source that has been used to make the labels in the first place.

In other words, instead of writing

```
let label = cell.contentView.subviews[0] as! UILabel
```

and then examining the enabled/disabled status of the label

you should write

```
cursus = cursusses[indexPath.row] as Cursus
```

and examine the availability of the `cursus`.

One general rule of thumb is that you should get very suspicious when you see code accessing components of `UITableViewCell` outside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Testing the state of a label is nearly universally an indication that the code is incorrect.

Comment: I see, thanks for your response. Combined with Wain and Marek's answers I could get it working. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Man you are doing that wrong. Only `tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    -> UITableViewCell` can dequeue cells and setup its contents.

To prevent selection you should react on `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath` and return `nil` to indicate that you don't want to select anything.

Main problem is that you are writing to complex methods. It is hard to figure out what are you doing and what is you intention. `(will/did)SelectRowAtIndexPath` should invoke only one/tow some simple methods, for example: perform a segue or load some data.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Since I'm self-learning iOS development I appreciate it. I was able to block the selection with `willSelectRowAtIndexPath` and combined with Wain and dasblinkenlight's answers I got exactly what I need.

Comment: Trust me with first paragraph I learned this rule painfully. All changes to table should be reported to the table by proper notification than `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will update cells automatically.